# How to get strings in parentheses into array with java

Tags: java, string, extract, apache-commons

Lets say I have string like this:

```
String q = "foo (one) bla (two) zoo key hola (tree) (four) five"
```

I want to extract the strings in parentheses into string array

```
so this would be true:
stringArray[3].equals("four")
```

Is there something in commons package or other trick to do this?

Comment: It would be easy to try the "would this work" question... had a hard time holding back the -1 for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\((.*?)\\)");

    Matcher m = p.matcher("abc (one) abc (two) abc");

    List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();

    while(m.find())
        result.add(m.group(1));
```